# Magento 1.8 CE Paypal Payments Pro error messages: edit customer error messages

Tags: magento, paypal, payment, message

I'm running magento 1.8 ce with Paypal Payments Pro, I'm trying to find a way to customise the error messages that are show to customers. When a payment fails due to the customer's card they see this message: "PayPal gateway has rejected request. This transaction cannot be processed (#15005: Processor Decline)." which isn't clear to a customer what the problem is.

Is there a way to change the error messages into more 'customer friendly' wording? For example "Sorry, your card has been declined, please try another method." I'm assuming Paypal generates the response message outside of Magento, so would it be possible for magento to 'read' and then overwrite them with custom versions?

So far, research has yielded very little, am I right in thinking that the messages are generated from paypal and not natively in magento?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Yeah fair one, it was a kind of non specific, 'broad' programing question. I guess I was expecting the only way to solve it would be to write a function to read then overwrite the paypal messages. There is very little info on this problem, so having any kind of thread on it is useful. But I take your point, it's not a typical "whats wrong with this code" kind of question.

Comment: I agree. I thought that the solution might be a programming one, but the question wasn't programmatic per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php

```
protected function _handleCallErrors($response)
```

{
... 
...

$exception->setMessage(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('PayPal gateway has rejected request. %s', $errorMessages));

....
...
}

Comment: Thanks Andrey, quite right, this does allow you to edit the first part of any paypal error message but it doesn't allow you to customise the individual error its self. But helpful none the less.

Comment: "but it doesn't allow you to customise the individual error" , You mean the second part This transaction cannot be processed (#15005: Processor Decline). ?

Comment: After looking at it again, you're spot on, i think this is the answer, i've implemented this and seem to achive what i wanted. Thanks Andrey, i've marked it as the answer.